# ReferenceError: ko is not defined when running unit test in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, jestjs

I am new to Jest and Stackoverflow posting.
I have been trying to add unit test cases for knockoutJS application but getting **ReferenceError: ko is not defined** error when running the test. Any help would be appreciated.

below is the package.json file.

```
    {
  "name": "jstesting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "eVIPs.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-html-reporters": "^3.0.8",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "knockout": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      [
        "jest-html-reporters",
        {
          "publicPath": "./html-report",
          "filename": "report.html",
          "openReport": false
        }
      ]
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true
  }
}
```

and this is the test file.

```
    import testLogin from '../loginPage';
import homeJS, { HomeViewModel } from '../Home';
```

Comment: Can you show us which file first references `ko`, and how you import knockout in that file?

Comment: Both files have "import ko from 'knockout' "statement.

Comment: Also wanted to know if Jest supports knockout.JS? I have been getting errors one after the other as soon as I resolve one.